# Strange behavior of list append()

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to identify from a text file, a set of words that appear at least some number of times within any single of the text file. I have a list to hold the qualifying words. The file is read line by line. In each line, words occurred in the line and their counts are put into a dictionary. Words with count number higher than threshold is appended to the list. The code operating on a single line looks as follows (I pseudo coded some parts that doesn't pertain to the problem):

```
words = []
candidates = {}

for line in text: 
    for word in line:
        if word in dict:
            candidates[word] += 1
        else
            candidates[word] = 1
    for word in candidates:
        if candidates[word] > threshold:
            if word not in words:
                words.append(word)
    # candidates.clear()
```

At the end of each line, I was hoping to empty the dictionary and not carry useless content in it. However, the line which I put after the `#` now: `dict.clear()` erases the content of the list, and leaves only the qualifying words in the final line. When this line is removed, the output is correct.

Can someone please explain why this is happening? Does the append() method of list class make local copy of the data or just maintain a pointer? Does the dictionary clear() method not only releases the dict's reference to the key value pairs, but also releases other objects' reference to them?

@EDIT: to address some of the comments, the word extraction in each line is pseudocode. I did not think this step is relevant to the problem. If you guys are interested, here's the original code. https://github.com/muyezhu/python/blob/master/freqword
This code looks for frequently occurring short DNA piece in a long sequence. Sample data can be downloaded at this link: http://rosalind.info/problems/1d/

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the python keywords as variables. By that I mean, you shouldn't use `list` and `dict` as variables.

Comment: `dict` object and the `list` object have nothing in common except the immutable string objects. Please check if you are doing something like `list = []` somewhere in the code or provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry, the original code doesn't have `list` and `dict` as variables. Made a silly mistake here.

Comment: Also, iterating a string with a for loop will give individual characters on every iteration not the words

Comment: I can't see why you would want to get rid of the dictionary at the end of each line.  Presumably you want to count the words across multiple lines in order to meet the threshold.  If you are trying to be efficient, then you certainly don't want to iterate through the dictionary with every line.  This pseudo code will make it very hard to determine what is going wrong.

Comment: A simple work-around would be to initialize the dictionary at the beginning of the for loop rather than outside of it.

Comment: @seaotternerd: I just tried, it didn't help to initialize dictionary at beginning of the loop. Words from earlier lines are still lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying your linked code with the linked dataset shows that you're only getting one set of updates to `kmers` because the outermost `for` loop only runs once.

This is due to the `range` call you're using: `range(range(0, len(genome) - L + 1, L - k)`. In the example data, `len(genome)` is `100`, `L` is `75` and `k` is `5`. That means your range is `range(0, 26, 70)`, which yields only `0` (the next value would be `70`, which is much greater than the upper bounds of `26`).

I'm pretty sure you don't want to give the `L - k` step argument to `range`. If you change the loop code to use `range(len(genome) - L + 1)`, you get the expected results in `kmers`: `['CGACA', 'GAAGA', 'AATGT']`.